# Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

```
 function ReservationScreens({ navigation }) {
  const [switchValue, setSwitch] = useState(false);
  const [loading, isLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data] = useState([data]);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        paddingTop: Platform.OS === "android" ? 30 : 0,
      }}
    >
      <View style={styles.top}>
        <Text style={styles.text_picker}>El Mirador</Text>
        <View></View>
        <View style={styles.top_buttons}>
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <Feather name="calendar" size={25} />
          </TouchableOpacity>

          <TouchableOpacity style={{ marginLeft: 25 }} >
            <Feather name="settings" size={25} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.subTop}>
        <Text style={styles.date_text}>{getCurrentDate()}</Text>
        <Switch
          style={styles.switcher}
          onValueChange={() => setSwitch(true)}
          value={switchValue}
        />
      </View>


      <View style={styles.midTop}>
        <Text>Sala</Text>
        <Text>Torn</Text>
      </View>

      <View style={{}}>
        {isLoading(true) ? (
          <ActivityIndicator style={{ marginTop: 100 }} size="large" />
        ) : (
          <FlatList
            data={data}
            style={{ marginTop: 10, borderRadius: 25 }}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <View style={styles.books}>
                <View>
                  <Text style={styles.book_hour_text}>Hora de reserva</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.name_text}>{item.name}</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{ marginStart: 15 }}>
                  <Text style={styles.phone_text}>{item.telephone}</Text>
                  <Text
                    style={{
                      fontSize: 14,
                      marginStart: 10,
                      color: "#393b44",
                    }}
                  >
                    {item.num_people} personas
                  </Text>
                </View>
                <TouchableOpacity style={{ marginTop: 20, marginStart: 15 }}>
                  <Feather name="chevron-down" size={25} />
                </TouchableOpacity>

                <View
                  style={{
                    borderWidth: 0.2,
                    flex: 1,
                    marginTop: 20,
                    marginBottom: 20,
                    marginEnd: 5,
                  }}
                ></View>
              </View>
            )}
          />
        )}
      </View>

  
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

**It throws an error:** *Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop*

I don't understand where the error is, because it was working before, I think the problem comes from the states but I don't know where, please can someone help me?
[There's the full error code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohByb.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of this as an infinite loop. Your dom is being rendered infinitely. There is something in your code that is setting state again and again.

I think the error is in this statement because you are resetting the state to true again and again causing an infinite loop :

```
isLoading(true) ? (
```

Change this too

```
loading === true ? (
```

OR

```
loading ? (
```